# Set custom navigation bar class in UINavigationController

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, xcode6-beta7

I have a custom navigationBar :

```
class Name_UINavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    // code
}
```

and I want to set it to my navigation controller programmatically. So I tried :

```
var navController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(
            navigationBarClass: object_getClass(Name_UINavigationBar),
            toolbarClass: nil)
// code
```

But it crash saying :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
    reason: 'MyProject.Name_UINavigationBar is not a subclass of UINavigationBar'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
let navController = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: YourNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass: nil)
```

I encountered the same error and was able to get it working again like that.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift there is no supported way to get the Class of an object. You're problem is almost certainly to do with the `object_getClass` method which I believe is no longer supported as of Beta 5.

I imagine APIs like this will either be updated, rewritten or simply deprecated soon. For now you will need to do it in Objective-C.

Comment: I'm on xcode 6 beta 7 and it doesn't say anything about object_getClass. But what you say seems to be a good explanation.